# Toggle button inside accordion using jquery

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui, toggle, accordion

I want to create a toggle button inside an accordian. Here is what I was trying to do.

Javascript

```
$j("div a").live('click', function() {
$j("#toggleButton").click(function () {
      $j("#test p").slideToggle("slow");
    });
});
```

HTML is:

```
  <div id="accordion">
    <h3><a href="#">Number 1</a></h3><div><h4> Error1:</h4><p> some contents here </p><div id="content1"><input type="button" value="Hide" id="toggleButton" style="float:right;"><div id="test"> <p>jhfsnv jv jsdhv jsdvb </p></div></div></div>
    <h3><a href="#">Number 2</a></h3><div><h4> Error2:</h4><p> some contents here </p><div id="content1"><input type="button" value="Hide" id="toggleButton" style="float:right;"><div id="test"> <p>jsa shsbc sjhv sf </p></div></div></div>
  </div>
```

Here is what I want to do:

When I open the accordion I should see the text "some contents here" and "Hide" button. When I click on the hide button the contents i.e."jhfsnv jv jsdhv jsdvb " should open.

I want to keep the "hide" button on all options of accordion. So different accordion options will have hide button but with different contents.  (Is there a easy way to keep the id of all the hide buttons and the text they contains same (although the contents while clicking on hide button are different)) But all these different contents are within different accordion options.

Comment: Be careful, you have `toggleButton` as an id in two different elements

Comment: I have and advice for you... Use on instead of live, live is already deprecated, just check out the jQuery documents. You should do something like $j("div a").on('click', function(){}) instead of $j("div a").live('click', function(){}).

Comment: @AndresOrozco - Your suggested use of `.on()` won't create a delegated handler like `.live()` does. Without knowing more of the html structure the nearest equivalent to `.live()` would be `$(document).on("click","div a", function() {})`

Comment: Well @nnnnnn Have you read the jQuery documentation? It talks about "don't use live, it's deprecated, use on instead". [Example Image](http://i.imm.io/zr5E.png) -> [jQuery Method](http://api.jquery.com/live/)

Comment: @AndresOrozco - My point is that the syntax you suggested won't do the same job as `.live()` so if the OP simply switched her code over it would break. The syntax I suggested _will_ do the same job. (As for whether I've read the doco, how do you think I know what the correct syntax is? It's right there on the page you linked to, and on the page for [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on)...)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this please **Working Demo** http://jsfiddle.net/stXP6/ **or** http://jsfiddle.net/z8Jns/

Oh and your HTML ain't valid I have rectified it a bit now using class. i.e. `id` defines identity of the element hence it should be unique.

Hope it fits your need `:)`

**code**

```
$(".test").hide();
$(".toggleButton").click(function() {
    $(this).next(".test").slideToggle("slow");
});​
```

**HTML**

```
<h3><a href="#">Number 1</a></h3><div><h4> Error1:</h4><p> some contents here </p><div id="content1"><input type="button" value="Hide" class="toggleButton" style="float:right;"><div class="test"> <p>jhfsnv jv jsdhv jsdvb </p></div></div></div>
<h3><a href="#">Number 2</a></h3><div><h4> Error2:</h4><p> some contents here </p><div id="content1"><input type="button" value="Hide" class="toggleButton" style="float:right;"><div class="test"> <p>jsa shsbc sjhv sf </p></div></div></div>
Here​​
```

Comment: @tats_innit Actually I am getting the contents dynamically in the accordion using ajax call. I tried to put the code inside the accordion click function. But I am not able to toggle the contents. When I open the accordion options I can still see the contents. Any suggestions what is going wrong?

Comment: @Tats_innit I have added this as a question please check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11827631/toggle-code-not-working-when-inserted-in-accordion-click-function-using-jquery