# toggle code not working when inserted in accordion click function using jquery

Tags: jquery, html, toggle, accordion, slidetoggle

This is followup question from my previous question "[Toggle button inside accordion using jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11822485/toggle-button-inside-accordian-using-jquery)" Although  did got reply for my question (I have fixed my code to reflect the same) but still the code is not working.

I am getting the contents dynamically in the accordion using ajax call. I tried to put the code inside the accordion click function. But I am not able to toggle the contents. When I open the accordion options I can still see the contents. Any suggestions what is going wrong?

I did checked on firebug and when I click on accordion it does goes to hide segment. While I click on the hide button it does execute the toggle statement. But I can still see the contents. (Which were supposed to be hidden).

Comment: i coudn't understand your problem but check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11504193/collapse-and-expand-tabs-jquery-simple-accordion/11504398#11504398

Comment: Have you change the id with class like suggested?

Comment: @barlasapaydin: Actually the code is working individually but when I put the code of hide and toggle inside the click function its not working since I can still look at the contents and the button does not toggle between the contents.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks all for comments. I figured it out. This was my typo mistake I did not declared class test as div once fixed its working.